# Index length in Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a **legacy** application where I have a table whose create definition looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.shops_urls (
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   id_shop INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   url VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, 
   
   PRIMARY KEY (id, id_shop),
   INDEX url (url),
   INDEX id_shop_url (id_shop, url) 
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB';
```

The legacy application is being revamped and migrated to Symfony. Hence the table/entity

```
/**
 * ShopsUrls
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ShopsUrlsRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      name="shops_urls",
 *      schema="my_schema",
 *      indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(name="url", columns={"url"}),
 *          @ORM\Index(name="id_shop_url", columns={"id_shop","url"})
 *      }
 * )
 */
class ShopsUrls
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_shop", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned":true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private ?int $id_shop;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=2000, nullable=false)
     */
    private ?string $url;
}
```

When executing `$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, the following errors is displayed:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes`

Executing the above SQL gives the same error. If we modify the indexes as follows, the SQL is executed without errors (hence table if created).

```
   INDEX url (url(100)),
   INDEX id_shop_url (id_shop, url(100))
```

### Question

Is there a way to specify length of index in Doctrine annonations ? Something like:

```
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      name="shops_urls",
 *      schema="my_schema",
 *      indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(name="url", columns={"url(100)"}),
 *          @ORM\Index(name="id_shop_url", columns={"id_shop","url(100)"})
 *      }
 * )
```

Executing `$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, gives the following error:

`There is no column with name 'url(100)' on table 'shops_urls'.`

Comment: Got the solution: options & "lengths"

    @ORM\Index(name="url", columns={"url"}, options={"lengths"={100}}),
    @ORM\Index(name="id_shop_url", columns={"id_shop","url"}, options={"lengths"={null,100}})

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the index length in the third argument `options` of the `ORM\Index` annotation.

```
@ORM\Index(name="url", columns={"url(100)"}, options={"lengths": {100}})
```

or as a list for a combined index

```
@ORM\Index(name="id_shop_url", columns={"id_shop", "url"}, options={"lengths": {10, 100}})
```

set null for those fields you want completely indexed

```
@ORM\Index(name="id_shop_url", columns={"id_shop", "url"}, options={"lengths": {null, 100}})
```